# Method to get the client ip address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proxy, ip-address

I'm developing an application where it seems likely that people will attempt to hide what their client IP address is behind a proxy server.

Is there a unified way to get what the actual client IP Address is behind the proxy? Looking at the [Ruby docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Request.html#M000706), it explicitly states that

```
request.remote_ip
```

and

```
request.remote_addr
```

both would return the proxy address and not the actual client IP and I'm thrown by the "may contain" descriptions in the rest of the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if the proxy supports [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For). I'd run some tests to be sure that `remote_ip` isn't what you're looking for - based on a quick glance at the code it attempts to read the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header.

Comment: If remote_ip is checking the "furthest" HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR then I don't have to worry about trying to sort that out myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm typing this from a machine that's behind a proxy. I'm not "hiding", it's how my organisation (and most others large enough to have a server) works. I don't have a fixed IP address: it's allocated dynamically. So I can't see how knowing my "current" IP address is going to help, since it'll be different tomorrow. Heck, I may be connected via a different proxy tomorrow (I work for a large organisation)!

At home, I have several machines connected through a router. Again, I don't have a fixed IP address: it's allocated dynamically by my ISP. It's a large ISP, so there's probably a proxy server somewhere upstream.

So I think what you want is not technically possible. What kind of application would make it "likely that people will attempt to hide what their client IP address is" anyway? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm creating an online voting application and want to take reasonable measures to prevent vote stuffing - checkout http://musicmachinery.com/2009/04/15/inside-the-precision-hack/ for a worst case scenario. 

I should probably have specified "Anonymous Proxy" in my original question as the examples you have listed (Corporate or Local NAT) are correct but manageable from my perspective.

Comment: A few years later here, but even if the IP changes from time to time, it's useful for high-level geographic information.  My ISP will probably give me a different IP from time to time, but they will all sort of look the same.  It would be apparent that I'm somewhere in the United States, for example.  That can be good enough for a lot of applications.